# How can I avoid duplicating props across similar Vue components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**Component Structure:**

[image: component structure]

I have many `button` components in my application and each one has a different `icon` within it (I've placed these `icons` in their own components so I can use them elsewhere). I would like these `icon` components to respond to *hover* events when the parent component is hovered over.

I have a solution, but there's repetition in it. For every button (`SettingsButton`, `HelpButton` etc.) I find myself writing the `hover` code in order to pass it to the `icon` component. Is there a way to avoid this?

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/p29fhygu/5/) for JS fiddle example.

```js
const { ref } = Vue;

const HelpIcon = {
    template: `<div :style="{ 'background': hover ? 'blue' : '' }"></div>`,

    props: {
        hover: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
        },
    },
};

const BaseButton = {
    template: `
        <a href="/" @click.prevent>
            <slot name="icon" />

            <span>
                <slot name="text" />
            </span>
        </a>
    `,
};

const HelpButton = {
    components: { BaseButton, HelpIcon },

    // _every_ button has to have `mouseover`, `mouseleave` and `hover` ref
    template: `
        <BaseButton @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false">
            <template #icon>
                <HelpIcon :hover="hover" />
            </template>

            <template #text>Help</template>
        </BaseButton>
    `,

    setup() {
        // _every_ button has this ref
        const hover = ref(false);
        return { hover };
    }
};

Vue.createApp({
    components: { HelpButton },
}).mount('#app');
```

Comment: Why not register the event handlers on `BaseButton`?

Comment: @YomS. When I do that I can't pass `hover` as a prop to what ever is in the `icon` slot.

Comment: @MattDeacalion could give the solution when you had tried out registering the event on basebutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `mixin` like :

```
const hoverable={
    props: {
        hover: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
        },
    },   
}
```

then add it to your icon mixins option :

```
const HelpIcon = {
    template: `<div :style="{ 'background': hover ? 'blue' : '' }"></div>`,
     mixins:[hoverable]
};
```

Try also to register the events handler in `BaseButton` then pass the `hover` via scoped slot :

```
const BaseButton = {
    template: `
        <a href="/" @click.prevent  @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false">
            <slot name="icon" :hover="hover" />
          
            <span>
                <slot name="text" />
            </span>
        </a>
    `,
 setup() {
        const hover = ref(false);
        return { hover };
    }
};
```

then :

```
 <BaseButton >
            <template #icon="{hover}" >
                <HelpIcon :hover="hover" />
            </template>

            <template #text>Help</template>
 </BaseButton>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8fv695nj/)